# After UNINSTALLING TortoiseSVN windows client my folder icons are gone!

Tags: windows-7, tortoise-svn

Does anyone know how to restore these icons?
I installed TortoiseSVN and then uninstalled and now my project icons are all screwed up.
This is on Windows 7 64-bit.

[image]

Comment: not trying to be a wiseguy, but have you rebooted since the uninstall?

Comment: Do the files open up with the proper program when you double click them? What are the file types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a reboot doesn't work you can rebuild the icon cache.  [Here](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t71.html) is a walk through of how to rebuild the cache.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. I usually don't reboot for weeks at a time, so this didn't even pop into my head. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Glad it worked, I do the same thing with rebooting.  Thanks to Chris_K too.